claiming less than what is specified
Let's suppose that the specifications thoroughly describe four components that make up the invention, A, B, C, and D.
In the specifications, it is clear that the inventor communicated that all four components are required.
However, when compared to prior art, only the components A, B, and C alone would be enough to be novel, non-obvious, useful, and enabled.
Can the inventor later file a continuation application to claim only A, B, and C, making for a broader claim?

Are all four really required? If so how can a claim only require three?


Can the inventor later file a continuation application to claim only A, B, and C, making for a broader claim?

MPEP 2172.01 "Unclaimed Essential Subject Matter" provides clear guidance to the contrary: "Such essential matter may include missing elements, steps or necessary structural cooperative relationships of elements described by the applicant(s) as necessary to practice the invention."
I suppose the assumption here is that inventors know from the start that fewer elements make for broader and more valuable claims, so if they require more elements in their description then that indicates that they weren't actually in possession of the broader invention with fewer elements at the time of filing.
(Note also that there are different types of continuations. It would not be possible with a divisional but might be possible with a continuation-in-part depending on whether the parent application published yet. But in any case it would not be entitled to the priority date of the original filing.)
